# AWK / KSH Shell Text Processing / Count By Groups

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

Given a file which contains this:

```
ID      NAME    COMPANY  YEAR
111     LUIS    TCS     2016
222     URSO    XYZ     2014
333     OMAR    ABC     2015
444     SANJIB  MABE    2012
111     LUIS    TCS     2015
444     SANJIB  MABE    2011
111     LUIS    TCS     2015
222     URSO    XYZ     2015
333     OMAR    ABC     2014
```

It's required to do 2 sorts, first by ID, then by Year, so far I managed to do that already. Next thing is to add an extra column with a count of every occurrence of the same ID, something like this.

```
ID      NAME    COMPANY  YEAR   Count
111     LUIS    TCS     2015    1
111     LUIS    TCS     2015    2
111     LUIS    TCS     2016    3
222     URSO    XYZ     2014    1
222     URSO    XYZ     2015    2
333     OMAR    ABC     2014    1
333     OMAR    ABC     2015    2
444     SANJIB  MABE    2011    1
444     SANJIB  MABE    2012    2
```

And so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a course work solving forum.

Comment: I'm sorry if I''m confused you, but this has nothing to do with a course, this is just a text processing task I'm trying to solve, because I'm kind of new to all of this kind of stuff.

Comment: the count for `222     URSO    XYZ     2015    2` is wrong - there's only one record with `222 -... 2015`. The same issue for `333     OMAR    ABC     2015    2` and `444     SANJIB  MABE    2012    2`

Comment: Yes I know, but the thing is that I want the output as I showed, I mean that the count value takes the ID as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
< file sort | awk '{print $0 "\t" ++n[$1]}'
```

Comment: I had something like this in a shell script for the header,body() {
    IFS= read -r header
    printf '%s\n' "$header"
    "$@"
}

body < data.dat  sort | awk '{print $0 "\t" ++n[$1]}'

Answer (score 1):

A single sort on the sample data provided returns output in the same order as your requested output.  Assuming the header line is not included in the sort.

```
sort datafile
```

The next step is to count the number of times we have seen the identical IDs to populate column 5.  We also replace the header to include the new column 5.

We will want to skip the original header line from your awk parsing.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "ID\tNAME\tCOMPANY\tYEAR\tCOUNT"} NR>1 {id_count[$1]++; print $0 "\t" id_count[$1]}' datafile
```

In case the first line of the datafile is a header, awk ignores that line by (requiring the line/record number to be greater than 1).

Just put the commands together by piping the first command to the second.  In this next instance, we assume the header line is not included in the output of sort.

```
sort datafile | awk 'BEGIN {print "ID\tNAME\tCOMPANY\tYEAR\tCOUNT"}  {id_count[$1]++; print $0 "\t" id_count[$1]}'
```

The sort command natively includes all fields so you end up with a sort by columns keeping IDs together, then names, then companies, then years.
The awk command prints a new header (more or less replicating the original) and appends the COUNT column.

The rest of the lines in the data are parsed by examining field 1 (ID) using an associative array.  Each line is printed as is with a tab and the number of times column 1 has been seen appended to it.

The final print statement may be confusing at first, but a whitespace character in awk is a concatenator.  The $0, the tab, and the value of the variable will all be squeezed together in the output.  Another way of writing this could have been;

```
printf "%s\t%d\n",$0,id_count[$1]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388373/116858) is good, but disregards the header of the data. It also assumes that a specific `ID` always corresponds to the same `NAME` and `COMPANY`.

If that's not the case, then you would have to do it slightly differently:

```
sort -k1,1 -k4,4 file.in | awk '{ print $0, ++n[$1] }'
```

To get the header correct:

```
sed '1d' file.in |
sort -k1,1 -k4,4 |
awk -vOFS="\t" \
   'BEGIN { print "ID", "NAME", "COMPANY", "YEAR", "Count" }
          { print $0, ++n[$1] }'
```

This strips the header from the input, sorts the file on `ID` and `YEAR` and then re-inserts the header with the new `Count` column. It then increments a counter for each `ID` and outputs the current value of this counter in the last column for each line of input:

```
ID      NAME    COMPANY YEAR    Count
111     LUIS    TCS     2015    1
111     LUIS    TCS     2015    2
111     LUIS    TCS     2016    3
222     URSO    XYZ     2014    1
222     URSO    XYZ     2015    2
333     OMAR    ABC     2014    1
333     OMAR    ABC     2015    2
444     SANJIB  MABE    2011    1
444     SANJIB  MABE    2012    2
```

If you want to let `awk` pick out the original header from the file and just add the `Count` header without having to explicitly type it in again, you can do that too:

```
sed -e '1w /tmp/header.txt' -e '1d' file.in |
sort -k1,1 -k4,4 |
awk -vOFS="\t" \
   'NR == 1 { getline h <"/tmp/header.txt"; print h, "Count" }
            { print $0, ++n[$1] }'

rm -f /tmp/header.txt
```

This makes `sed` write the header to the file `/tmp/header.txt`. When the first record is read by `awk`, this file is read into the variable `h` and outputted together with the new column `Count`. The rest of the `awk` script works as previously and produces the same output.

The `/tmp/header.txt` file is guaranteed to exist for the `awk` script to read as it's not read until the first input record arrives. At that point, the `sort` has consumed all input from `sed` which means that the header file must have been written. Reading it in a `BEGIN` block would potentially *not* work.